# Create SharePoint list item with lookup field with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create list items with Microsoft Graph's new SharePoint endpoint. My URL is as follows:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items

Calling this URL with POST, and a body like this:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "Title": "test",
    }
}
```

.. works! But if I include a lookup field, the lookup field is always empty. I have tried with

```
"{columnName}": "id",

"{columnName}": "id;#value",

"{columnName}": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference", //and others like this
    "Id": "id",
    "Value": "value",
}

"{columnName}": "value",
"{columnName}Id": "id",
```

None of these seems to work. Some give an error like "The request is malformed or incorrect.", others go through, but doesn't include the lookup field.

The documentation for this is scarce (if any), and I have found very little information on google (apart from someone asking the same question with no answers). Anyone that got this to work yet? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

I have got this to work with people fields where the multiple selection option was DISABLED. So if you have a person field which allows one person only, the following works.

```
"{columnName}LookupId": id
```

Additionally, the id still needs to be the SP ID and not the graph user GUID. This ID changes from site to site.

Comment: My filed name is "Manager" but using fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("{Manager}LookupId", userId);  I get Field '{Manager}LookupId' is not recognized

Comment: Remove the curly brackets and try it again.

Comment: Yes, I should have removed the comment, My bad :-)

Comment: @OferGal No worries. And keep the comment. It helps people who come across this from Google.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a lookup column in the following format

```
"Office": "London",
"OfficeLookupId", "16"
```

Where Office is the name of the column

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I try this, I get an error 400 bad request, with message "Field 'KundeLookupId' is not recognied".
I have a column named "Kunde", that is a lookup field. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you do an exapand=fields on the items can you see the two fields listed i.e. Kunde and KundeLookupId also have you tried on beta too

Comment: Yes, I can get the data, but I cannot post it - even when following the same schema I get returned. I have tested against both v1.0 and beta

Comment: Might want to raise with the Microsoft Graph team as a bug as this is how it's documented. I'll share this question to their twitter feed too

Comment: Lose the quotes on the id. Use 16 instead of "16"

Comment: Additionally, this only works on people columns which do not have multiple selections available.