# Set value for Multiple Lookup list in sharepoint in C#

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I try to set the sharepoint list items and update lists, right now the sharepoint list is a lookup with multiple value 
I call 
POST
/sites/{}/lists/{list_guid}/items/{item_id}/fields

with Json

```
{
    "MyListLookUpValue":[
          "LookupId":1,
          "LookupValue":"My name",
          "Email":"my@email.se",
     ]
}
```

(This isn't the code i use, but a representation)

I have found that i should specify the type but the thing is that i dont know the typ if it would be a list of Strings i could add

```
"MyListLookUpValue@odata.type":"Collection(Edm.String)"
```

Anyone that has this similar issue that you have to specify the type ?

Dont understand why they need to make it so hard.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
    "message": "A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available. When the model is specified, each value in the payload must have a type which can be either specified in the payload, explicitly by the caller or implicitly inferred from the parent value.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "2aaa2c86-f922-414b-b9c9-f892588b0bea",
        "date": "2019-02-28T17:05:05"
    }
}
```

}


**SOLUTION**

After help from comments i got this answer which worked

```
{
    "MyListLookUpValueLookupId@odata.type" : "Collection(Edm.Inte32)"
    "MyListLookUpValueLookupId": [1,2,3]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create SharePoint list item with lookup field with Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707051/create-sharepoint-list-item-with-lookup-field-with-microsoft-graph)

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Exactly you that i wanted to get help from, you have help me before! I didn't get help from that duplication. 
Do you have any idea how this could be done.
Update question with Error

Comment: I believe you want to just set the `id`, not the entire set: `{"LookupField": 1}`

Comment: Do you mean like this "columnName":[{id}] or "columnName": [{"id": 7}]? First  case dosen't work second case complains about Type. Maybe problem is that i try this in postman ?

Comment: It should be `columnNameLookupId`, not simply `columnName`

Comment: I can't get it to work, the lookup is to a list under the same SharePoint site.i know that with create groups you can use odata.bindfor member and owners, can I do something similar here ?

Comment: Thansk Marc, columnNameLookupId Worked.
I did miss the type and added a s which made it fail