# Creating Item in SP List oDat.Type for People attribute

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I need to create an item with Person/People field.

I am able to populate fields like Title, DateTime, TextField as seen below, but I am not able to populate Person field at all.

I have tried sending Display Name, User ID and UPN.

```
var fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet();
fieldValueSet.AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("Title@odata.type", "Edm.String");
fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("Title", task.Title);
fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("Plan@odata.type", "Edm.String");
fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("Plan", plan.Title);
fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("Assigned@odata.type", "Edm.String");
fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("Assigned", assignee.UserPrincipalName);
fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("DueDate@odata.type", "Edm.String");
fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("DueDate", task.DueDateTime);

var listItem = new ListItem
{
   Fields = fieldValueSet
};

await graphServiceClient.Sites["SPURL:/sites/ITOddeleni:"].Lists["ListName"].Items
                                    .Request()
                                    .AddAsync(listItem)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your user principal name look like an email? (e.g. `some.person@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com`). If that is the case then you should probably try to convert it to a sharepoint-claim version: `i:0#.f|membership|some.dude@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com`.

If you have an authenticated ClientContext in your app, then you could resolve the username by calling the [SharePoint utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee540627(v=office.15)):
`Utility.ResolvePrincipal(context, context.Web, userEmail, PrincipalType.User, PrincipalSource.All, null, true);`
If you don't have a context then you can try and combine strings (not as robust, but should work as well).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929817/set-value-for-multiple-lookup-list-in-sharepoint-in-c-sharp) suggests that you should try and set the LookupId value for the field (sorta the same way you set user values using the SharePoint's REST api):

```
var assigneeLookupId = // Get the assignee's user id on the site (wssid)
fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("AssignedLookupId@odata.type", "Edm.Int32");
fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("AssignedLookupId", assigneeLookupId);
```

The following schema would allow you to insert multiple person values:
SOLUTION 
After help from comments i got this answer which worked

```
{
    "AssignedLookupId@odata.type" : "Collection(Edm.Int32)"
    "AssignedLookupId": [1,2,3]
}
```

This approach is in line with the way MS Graph returns values for Lookup fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, correct my UPN looks like an email address (classic UPN), I will give it a shot on Monday, will let you know about the result.

Comment: Tried to send via string some.person@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com and that did not work. Will try the ID later.

Comment: could not make that to work, would not accept i:0#.f|membership|some.dude@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com :-( any other suggestion?

Comment: Try using LookupId fields.

Comment: Just reading the related threads to the links you sent to me, seems I will have to populate a column of single line of text and try to make a flow...

Comment: I can't figure out where I can get the assigneeLookupId

Comment: I have managed to add person to the lookupfield, fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("AssignedLookupId@odata.type", "Edm.Int32"); fieldValueSet.AdditionalData.Add("AssignedLookupId", 14);
But I have no clue how to add multiple people as it does not accept collection and array of Ints, also I have no clue how to get the SharePoint person ID using graph... but still making a progress :D

Comment: the abovementioned answer had this snippet: {
    "MyListLookUpValueLookupId@odata.type" : "Collection(Edm.Int32)"
    "MyListLookUpValueLookupId": [1,2,3]
}

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but i am an idiot... I forgot to enable multi choice for the column on the SP, thank you very much for your help :-) now I just need to get all the people from the sitecollection somehow :-)

Comment: Alright, the all users part is just a list from which I extracted Id of the users + the name as from a normal list, thank you very much once more for your help :-)